# Zabbix housekeeper processes more than 75% busy

Tags: configuration, monitoring, zabbix

We are using Zabbix 3.2 but can´t fix this problem:

"Zabbix housekeeper processes more than 75% busy"

What could solve the problem? Any suggestions? We think that the values per second is to high ...

```
Status of Zabbix:

Number of hosts (enabled/disabled/templates)    129 62 / 20 / 47

Number of items (enabled/disabled/not supported)    30870   26192 / 4602 / 76

Number of triggers (enabled/disabled [problem/ok])  9438    9265 / 173 [44 / 9221]

Required server performance, new values per second  847.06
```

Our Server conf is the following:

StartPollers=356

StartTrappers= 30

StartPingers= 2

CacheSize= 512M

HistoryCacheSize= 1024M

Answer (score 3):

For how long is the housekeeper busy? You can see that in the graphs, provided by the default Zabbix server template.

If it's up to 10 minutes, you can probably ignore that and tune the trigger to be less sensitive.

If it's more, it is a general Zabbix DB performance issue. Consider the following, roughly in this order:

- reduce history retention periods. If you have been using the defaults of 90 days, drop it to 7, if possible. Note that this change will take some time to have an effect if your items have a lot of history data
- reduce new values per second - extend item intervals
- tune the database - you can find basic suggestions [in the Zabbix manual](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/appendix/performance_tuning)
- use database partitioning (but be ready for manually fixing any issues)
- have more memory & faster disks for your database server

Comment: hey richiv, i tuned the history retention periods and reduced the values per second. nothing changed. moreover i tried to tune the server configuration but could not change something.

Comment: to have better controll i added email actions for special server downtimes. now my values per second are even more

Comment: That is extremely vague. By how much did you reduce NVPS? How did you change retention periods? Did really _nothing_ change? What does "but could not change something" mean?

Comment: on the graph screen: the first housekeeper run was after setting down the NPVS from 990 to around 550. i thought it would be fine now. but after some time the housekeeper stucked at 100% and everythink is still the same

Comment: It might get better once it has chewed the older data. In any case, this would be a longer investigation and a performance tuning that cannot be answered in a single answer - see the checklist in the answer above.